# Java emoji conversion to xml: what libraries exist?

Tags: java, unicode, mime, emoji

I am transforming MIME messages to XML so that I can submit them to a mail merge service as SOAP requests, but Emoji are giving me problems ([the smiley 😃](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f603/index.htm) for example, which I'd like to have converted to `&#128515;`).

I'm using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to handle my conversions but it doesn't properly encode emoji and other high/low surrogate pairs (see the example test case below).  It is possible that I am missing some crucial xstream configuration component.

I have found [this project](https://github.com/u1tnk/emoji-converter) that is based on [this project](https://code.google.com/p/emoji4unicode/source/browse/trunk/data/emoji4unicode.xml) which does conversions for specific Japanese cell phone providers via a hard-coded mapping, but I feel like this problem is probably solved more elegantly in existing Oracle or third-party (Apache, etc.) libraries.

From what I've read and heard [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) addresses this issue for PHP but I'd like to stay in the Java/Groovy world for emoji conversion so I can use a compatible library.

What tools/approaches are you using to handle emoji conversion to XML on the JVM?

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class XStreamTest extends TestCase {
    public void testXStreamEmojiEncoding() {
        final String expected = "Open mouth smiley &#128515; and two chicken heads followed by a period &#128020;&#128020;.";
        final String original = "Open mouth smiley  and two chicken heads followed by a period .";

        final XStream xStream = new XStream();

        final String returned = xStream.toXML(original);

        assertEquals("<string>" + expected + "</string>", returned);
    }
}
```

The above test looks for an HTML decimal representation of the emoji but I'll accept other formats that will work for MIME.

Comment: I don't see how any XML library that handles characters outside of the BMP correctly should have trouble with Emojis (even if they where just added to Unicode recently). Could you post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Just get a XML library that supports Unicode 2.0 (which was published in 1996, seventeen years ago) or later (primary feature of interest here being UTF-16 support). XStream clearly doesn't; file a bug report and shop for a new one.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I will investigate some other alternatives -- suggestions welcomed.  It appears that my application's use of XStream is somewhat misguided since XStream isn't meant to be an encoder per se.

Comment: Your `expected` contains "two chickens" and your `original` contains "two chicken heads".

Comment: Also: why do you expect numeric references to be created for this? XML may just encode the values directly.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: c/p error on the heads vs. bodies issue. To your other point, see my comment to RMartinhoFernandes.  I appear to have fallen victim to confusing which part of my app is doing the conversion with which part is doing the escaping.  I will close this post once I can and/or answer with an example using a library that does the encoding properly.  I'll remove the XStream tag since this is out of their wheelhouse (although it appears I can write a custom encoding component to use with XStream).

Comment: @eebbesen did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm having a similar problem. Damn emoji.

Comment: @l15a I have not found a solution to the question posed in this post. Per R.MartinhoFernandes's comments this should be being handled by Unicode 2.0-compliant libraries.  I was asking XStream to do something it wasn't designed to do: conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently wrote a library for this: [emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java)
Here is the kind of output you would get:

```
String str = "An awesome string with a few emojis!";
String result = EmojiParser.parseToAliases(myString);
System.out.println(myString);
// Prints:
// "An &#128512;awesome &#128515;string with a few &#128521;emojis!"
```

You can either add the jar to your project or use the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vdurmont<groupId>
  <artifactId>emoji-java<artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- Or whatever the version will be when you read this post -->
</dependency>
```